# tick mark/range problem on graph generated using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I'm having a little difficulty getting a tick mark on a graph generated using TikZ to appear correctly. The code is below and the problem can be seen in the vertical axis of the second graph (b). How could I fix this little problem?

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[hard limiter]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
            \begin{axis}[
                xtick=\empty,
                ytick={-1, 0, 1},
                xlabel=${x}$,
                ylabel=${f_{h}\left(x\right)}$,
                width=150 pt]
                \addplot+[mark=none, black]
                    coordinates{
                        (-1, -1)
                        (0, -1)
                        (0, 1)
                        (1, 1)
                    };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \label{figure:hard_limiter_1}
    }
    \\
    \subfigure[threshold logic]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
            \begin{axis}[
                ymin=-1,
                xtick=\empty,
                ytick={-1, 0, 1},
                xlabel=${x}$,
                ylabel=${f_{t}\left(x\right)}$,
                width=150 pt]
                \addplot+[mark=none, black]
                    coordinates{
                        (-1, 0)
                        (0, 0)
                        (1, 1)
                    };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \label{figure:threshold_logic_1}
    }
    \subfigure[sigmoid]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
            \begin{axis}
                [
                    xtick=\empty,
                    ytick={-1, 0, 1},
                    xlabel=${x}$,
                    ylabel=${f_{s}\left(x\right)}$,
                    width=150 pt
                ]
                \addplot+[mark=none, smooth, black] {2/(1+e^(-x))-1};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \label{figure:sigmoid_1}
    }
    \caption{three representative nonlinearities}
    \label{figure:three_representative_nonlinearities_1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You are quite right. I added the wrong code (I'm doing too many things at once...). I've added the correct code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility (I just added a single coordinate with y-coordinate equal to -1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[hard limiter]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
            \begin{axis}[
                xtick=\empty,
                ytick={-1, 0, 1},
                xlabel=${x}$,
                ylabel=${f_{h}\left(x\right)}$,
                width=150 pt]
                \addplot+[mark=none, black]
                    coordinates{
                        (-1, -1)
                        (0, -1)
                        (0, 1)
                        (1, 1)
                    };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \label{figure:hard_limiter_1}%
    }%
    \\
    \subfigure[threshold logic]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
            \begin{axis}[
                xtick=\empty,
                ytick={-1, 0, 1},
                xlabel=${x}$,
                ylabel=${f_{t}\left(x\right)}$,
                width=150 pt]
                \addplot+[mark=none, black]
                    coordinates{
                        (-1, 0)
                        (0, 0)
                        (1, 1)
                    };
                \addplot+[mark=none] coordinates{(-1,-1)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \label{figure:threshold_logic_1}%
    }\quad
    \subfigure[sigmoid]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
            \begin{axis}
                [
                    xtick=\empty,
                    ytick={-1, 0, 1},
                    xlabel=${x}$,
                    ylabel=${f_{s}\left(x\right)}$,
                    width=150 pt
                ]
                \addplot+[mark=none, smooth, black] {2/(1+e^(-x))-1};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \label{figure:sigmoid_1}%
    }
    \caption{three representative nonlinearities}
    \label{figure:three_representative_nonlinearities_1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I suppressed some spurious spaces from your code.

By the way, `subfigure` is an obsolete package and shouldn't be used anymore. You could use [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) instead.

Here's an example of your code, using `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
            \begin{axis}[
                xtick=\empty,
                ytick={-1, 0, 1},
                xlabel=${x}$,
                ylabel=${f_{h}\left(x\right)}$,
                width=150 pt]
                \addplot+[mark=none, black]
                    coordinates{
                        (-1, -1)
                        (0, -1)
                        (0, 1)
                        (1, 1)
                    };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{hard limiter}
\label{figure:hard_limiter_1}%
\end{subfigure}\\[1ex]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
            \begin{axis}[
                xtick=\empty,
                ytick={-1, 0, 1},
                xlabel=${x}$,
                ylabel=${f_{t}\left(x\right)}$,
                width=150 pt]
                \addplot+[mark=none, black]
                    coordinates{
                        (-1, 0)
                        (0, 0)
                        (1, 1)
                    };
                \addplot+[mark=none] coordinates{(-1,-1)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{threshold logic}
\label{figure:threshold_logic_1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
            \begin{axis}
                [
                    xtick=\empty,
                    ytick={-1, 0, 1},
                    xlabel=${x}$,
                    ylabel=${f_{s}\left(x\right)}$,
                    width=150 pt
                ]
                \addplot+[mark=none, smooth, black] {2/(1+e^(-x))-1};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{sigmoid}
\label{figure:sigmoid_1}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{three representative nonlinearities}
\label{figure:three_representative_nonlinearities_1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]